# Howto calculate with fractions in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am new to objective C and I started to learn the basics in iOS development.

How can I easily calculate with fractions in Objective C?

> **Example 1:** 1/8000 * 60
>
> **Example 2:** 1/640 / 1/400

I need to have the result (if its < 1) as a fraction, too.

Comment: You can implement a `Fraction` class. This book (or the old edition I have does, anyway) has an excellent tutorial - it's a great book as well. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Objective-C-Automatic-Reference-Developers/dp/0321811909/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1338374106&sr=1-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would implement a new class, say `Fraction` which has two properties, the numerator and denominator. I would then implement four (or more if necessary) of the following functions:

```
- (Fraction*) add:(Fraction*)operand;
- (Fraction*) subtract:(Fraction*)operand;
- (Fraction*) multiply:(Fraction*)operand;
- (Fraction*) divide:(Fraction*)operand;
- (Fraction*) invert;
+ (Fraction*) fractionByAdding:(Fraction*)op1 to:(Fraction*)op2;
+ (Fraction*) fractionBySubtracting:(Fraction*)op1 from:(Fraction*)op2;
+ (Fraction*) fractionByMultiplying:(Fraction*)op1 with:(Fraction*)op2;
+ (Fraction*) fractionByDuviding:(Fraction*)op1 by:(Fraction*)op2;
+ (Fraction*) fractionByInverting:(Fraction*)operand;
```

In these methods, do the usual arithmetic you learned in school. Remember to simplify if both numerator and denominator has common divisors.

EDIT: Example implementation for one of these functions:

```
- (Fraction*) add:(Fraction*)operand {
    return [Fraction fractionByAdding:self to:operand];
}

+ (Fraction*) fractionByAdding:(Fraction*)op1 to:(Fraction*)op2 {
    int num = (op1.numerator * op2.denominator) + (op2.numerator * op1.denominator);
    int denom = op1.denominator * op2.denominator;
    return [[Fraction alloc] initWithNumerator:num andDenominator:denom];
}
```

Optionally you could add a `reduce` or `simplify` method and possibly an `allowReducible` property and an `isIrreducible` method. You could also implement `isEqual` and `compareTo` methods. A `description` should just print "a/b" as an `NSString`.

Comment: Great input! Thank you very much Svein. The `isEqual` and `compareTo` methods are necessary, because I want to store some of these objects in an sortable array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type cast.

```
 int x = 1;
 int y = 8000;
 int z = 60;

 float result  =  ((float)x) / y * z;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate with decimal numbers by using `float` variables. However, there is no direct way to get the result of the calculation as a fraction, you will always get another `float`, i. e. a decimal number. There are algorithms to convert decimal numbers into fractions, but it's not a language feature of Objective-C.

Comment: OP asks not for decimal numbers, but fractions. Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: Yes, I read that. But since fractions are not possible without writing dozens of lines of code for a fraction class, I am telling the OP what they can do instead: Work with decimal numbers (another way of describing the same numbers) and use a suitable algorithm to convert the result into a fraction.